# MVC5 ICollection<T> remove entity using RemoveAt c# EF 6.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I am upgrading my MVC 3 application / Linq-To-Sql to MVC 5 Entity Framework 6.1.  I have a list of items (id, name, etc..).  To change the list the user can add items or delete by adding or deleting table row.  Using form collection I check the new items and delete the items that were present in the old list.  Using the following:

```
//.....
List<int> idsToKeep = new List<int>();
for (int i = 0; i < visit.Students.Count; i++)
{
  Students om = visit.Students.ElementAt(i);
  if (om.StudentsId == 0)
    continue;
  bool itemExists = false;
  int itemToDelete = 0;
  foreach (int id in idsToKeep)
    if (om.StudentsId == id)
    {
      itemExists = true;
    }
    else
    {
      itemToDelete = id;
    }

  if (!itemExists)
  {
    var entitySet = visit.Students.Where(x => x.StudentsId == 0 || idsToKeep.Contains(x.StudentsId)).ToList();
    entitySet.RemoveAt(i);
    //      _studentRepository.RemoveStudentsType(itemToDelete); 
    //    visit.Students.RemoveAt(i);
    i--;
  }
}
```

In Linq-to-Sql, I used:

```
visit.Students.RemoveAt(i);
```

Could not resolve RemoveAt because the list is ICollection.  So I used:

```
var entitySet = visit.Students.Where(x => x.StudentsId == 0 || idsToKeep.Contains(x.StudentsId)).ToList();
entitySet.RemoveAt(i);
```

The program keep circling and nothing happens!  Would appreciate your suggestions

Comment: Have you forget call the SaveChanges method at the DbContext object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are removing an entity from a *copy* of the collection tracked by Entity Framework. Sure enough, that change goes unnoticed by your context as it is completely unaware of the copy: it only registers changes in the original `ICollection<T>` (i.e. `visit.Students`).

You should consider finding the concrete entity at the correct index first - possibly by using LINQ's 'ElementAt` like so:

```
var entityAtIndex = visit.Students.ElementAt(i);

visit.Students.Remove(entityAtIndex);
```

Or, better yet, just use `visit.Students.Remove(om)`, as it will point to the exact instance you wanted to remove in the first place.

Comment: Had to add  studentRepository.Delete(om); Thanks